# WCF routing + WIF

Tags: wif, wcf-routing

How does the new routing service deal with security? According to http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/applisec/archive/2011/12/12/wcf-routing-and-message-security.aspx, it might be difficult when default windows security is not chosen (typically a simple username/password scenario).

Can wcf routing actually support a scenario where the router receives a WS-Security secured message over HTTP and forwards it to another server over HTTP, without unwrapping the security token?

My scenario is as follows:

1. A server (relying party), a custom STS with username/password authentication and a client. We use ws2007FederationHttpBinding and message security.
2. Now we setup wcf routing, it works with basicHttp or wsHttp.
3. Then we using WIF, we can instanciate proxies, the STS generates claims, but it fails at the first service call. It seems the router is waiting for the certificate definition (included, otherwise we get an error), then seems to require Cardspace UI (while in fact we're using username/password).

If so, would you have an example ?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that noone has a better answer for this question, it looks like my own workflow question i posted past week :(

Answer (score 0):

Good question, i couldn't find anything about this on google yet beside this question also being unanswered on msdn. I don't think this is added out of the box as normally u would need to use delegatation (ActAs) whenever u want to route the request to another service.

The only solution i can think of is creating a message inspector and use that one in your WCF Routing Service. And ofcourse u'll need to use *"SupportInteractive = false"*

I did found something that might be the answer, see the following post (ignore silverlight lol) http://zamd.net/2011/02/08/silverlight-claim-based-security/

Zamd says:
For the 2nd part I have implemented a **message inspector** along with an extension method which makes it super easy to **attach the SAML with outgoing messages**.